# Nested lists modify properties on depth

Tags: lists, nesting

How can I control the behavior of formatting(font size, bold, italics, underline, etc...) depending on the depth of a set of nested environments?

That is, I'd like the top level to be bold and huge while the inner most levels to be small and normal.

Some depths will have italics, etc..

Basically the formatting is consistent across the nesting level but I don't want to have to create formatting for every nest manually(since the lists are large with many nesting).

right now I have a ton of formatting macro's. I'd like a sort of CSS approach. e.g.,

```
\nestlevel{1}{\huge}
\nestlevel{2}{\Large\underlinemode}
\nestlevel{3}{\large}
```

etc...

(the idea is that I can set the size and other properties(`\underlinemode` makes all test underline)

the environments naturally revert to the previous styles when exiting an environment

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It certainly feels like `enumitem` should be able to handle this with `\setlist`, but no such option exists. Good question. Note: For a more CSS-like approach, use semantic formatting better: `\newcommand\ItemTypeFormat{\Large\underlinemode}`.

Comment: @SeanAllred But the whole issue is that the formatting changes depending on the depth. Because of the large lists I have to specify a lot of macro's. This becomes very tedious and is not easily manageable.

Comment: Rest assured that I understand what you're going after, I'm merely suggesting another layer of indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enumitem it is easy to add code to some list depth:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,color}

\setlist[1]{before=\huge}
\setlist[2]{before=\tiny\color{red}}
\begin{document}
abc
\begin{itemize}
\item blub
 \begin{itemize}
  \item blblb
 \end{itemize}
\item blabla 
\end{itemize}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does have some nice features and probably will do what I need. I have a problem: How to specify bold like textbf without having to specify the text. e.g., setlist[1]{before=\textbf} does not make the text bold. (because \textbf wants an argument.

Comment: @user4780446 `before=\bfseries`

Comment: Thanks, Now I need to underline but see no underline series equivalent. (I have to specify this stuff in the setlist macro and since ther eis no argument I have to use argumentless macro's... yet these don't seem to be too common.

Comment: Underlining won't work in this setup: There is no switch for underline.  And if you would try to tweak the list so that it passes its content to `ul` or `ulem`: it would be very fragile. The only safe solution is a dedicated "underlined" font - you could create it as virtual font with fontinst but it is not easy.